# Append Json Data To Array - Firebase/Swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to append data from Firebase to a variable called `var itemNumbers: [[String: AnyObject]]!` that belongs to an NSObject. This is how the fetch looks like:

```
        let orderItems = snapDict["itemNumbers"] as! [String:String]
        self.NSOBJECT.itemNumbers.append(orderItems as [String : AnyObject]) 
        print(orderItems)
```

When I do this the app breaks exactly where I try to append orderItems to the array. This is my error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

JSON:

```
{ "order": {
      "itemNumbers" : {
         "1": "Item Description",
         "2": "Item Description"
                      }
           }   
}
```

Do I need to convert orderItems into something else before I try to append it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where is the itemNumbers key ?

Comment: @cosmos can you trying with my answer

Comment: try this . self.NSOBJECT.itemNumbers.append(orderItems as [String : String])

Comment: Maybe changing the `var itemNumbers: [[String: AnyObject]]!` to `var itemNumbers: [[String: String]]!` ???

Comment: @cosmos your json is still invalid

Comment: This is the error I am getting now:  cannot convert [[String: String]] to type [String:String] in coercion.

Comment: json invalid please check the https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: why [[String: String]]  ? it should be [String: String]

Comment: @cosmos Still one bracket is missing but you can try this `let orderItems = snapDict["order"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                    self.NSOBJECT.itemNumbers.append(orderItems)`

Comment: Still gave me the coercion error...

Comment: var itemNumbers: [[String: String]]! what about that variable?

Comment: "production_companies":[  
      {  
         "name":"Regency Enterprises",
         "id":508
      },
      {  
         "name":"Fox 2000 Pictures",
         "id":711
      },
      {  
         "name":"Taurus Film",
         "id":20555
      },
      {  
         "name":"Linson Films",
         "id":54050
      },
      {  
         "name":"Atman Entertainment",
         "id":54051
      },
      {  
         "name":"Knickerbocker Films",
         "id":54052
      }
   ],

Comment: how should I make the variable? An array of hashes? Clearly my json model is flawed.

Comment: which one for ?

Comment: the one that belongs to the NSObject

Comment: How can I make it an array of hashes?

Comment: @cosmos is your itemNumbers array or CSV?

Comment: Its an Array var itemNumbers: [[String: AnyObject]]!

Comment: @cosmos I mean in json?

Comment: No idea. Sorry. How can I know and I will check?

Comment: where you found the json ?

Comment: my database. Firebase

Comment: well if you want to append **order** then use  [[String: AnyObject]] on the other hand append **itemNumbers** for [String:String]

Comment: can you update your answer? so that I can select it.

Comment: @cosmos your itemsNumbers json should be as `"itemNumbers" : [{
        "1": "Item Description"
    },
    { "2": "Item Description"
                     
    }
]`

Comment: how can I do that? How should I declare the variable so that I can send that information to firebase?

Comment: @cosmos see my answer..that should be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your json as whole lot of fields are incorrect.

Make your variable itemNumbers from

`var itemNumbers: [[String:AnyObject]]!`

to

```
 var itemNumbers: [[String:AnyObject]] = [] //if nil instantiate
```

as `itemsNumbers` is optional.

And append as

```
 let order = jsonDictionary["order"] as! [String:AnyObject]
 let tempItemNumbers = order["itemNumbers"] as! [String:AnyObject]
 self.NSOBJECT.itemNumbers.append(tempItemNumbers)
 print( self.NSOBJECT.itemNumbers)
```

Comment: could not cast value of nsdictionary to nsarray. Also, I am accessing cart through the database reference so I do not need to use it to access tempItemNumbers right?

Comment: now the problem is how should I send it to firebase? let cartVal = ["item":"1"]["item2":"2"] like that???

Comment: I am not sure how to create this when I set the value on the database reference. Never done this , any clues? This will help me greatly.

Comment: @cosmos Your can make your hierarchy as `{
  "order": {
    "itemNumbers": {
      {
        "1": "Item Description"
      },
      {
        "2": "Item Description"
      }
    }
  }
}` ..For reference how to strucuture see [here](https://www.appcoda.com/firebase/) or [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2)

Answer (score 1):

**mention comment**

*well if you want to append `order` then use `[[String: AnyObject]]` on the other hand append `itemNumbers` for `[String:String]`*

```
      guard  let  itemNumbers= snapDict["itemNumbers"] as? [String:String]  else{
         return
     }

      self.NSOBJECT.itemNumbers.append(itemNumbers)
```

or

```
      guard  let  orderItems = snapDict["order"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]  else{
         return
     }

      self.NSOBJECT.itemNumbers.append(orderItems)
```

Note : avoid the problematic implicit conversion  `[[String: AnyObject]]!`

Comment: I added ` self.NSOBJECT.itemNumbers.append(orderItems! as [String : AnyObject])` and this was the output: [["item": 1]]

Comment: Is this how I should send the data to Firbase? let ordertems = ["item":"1"]["item2":"2"] in order to receive it like your example? I assign this to the key orderItems.

Comment: (ill keep working on this tomorrow) thanks for the help.